# Segmentation fault when using a 1D array

Tags: arrays, c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    //Initialize array

    int n; // n is use to decide the size of array 
    int x[n];
    int y[n];
    printf("enter the size of array:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    if (n > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            printf("enter elements : \n");
            scanf("%d", &x[i]);
        }
    }

    printf("Array in reverse order: \n");
    //Loop through the array in reverse order
    for (int i = n - 1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++)
    {
        y[j] = x[i];
        printf("%d ", y[j]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In the above program, I have created a array whose size can be decided by the user. The user can also put elements in it.

After that I want to reverse this array and store the data in another array. But I get this error again and again. I am using CodeBlocks with the GCC compiler.

Comment: What is the value of `n`  in the moment you set x as the size of the arrays?

Comment: @DavidRanieri here I declared n because I want to create an equal another array y, so the reverse value can be printed

Comment: With variable length arrays you can decide the size at runtime, but this size must be known before the assignment, not two lines later.

Answer (score 1):

When the `x` and `y` arrays are created, `n` is uninitialized. There's no knowing how large these arrays will be.  You loops are almost certainly accessing the array out of bounds.

You want to read `n`, then create the arrays. Of course you *also* want to error check the result of `scanf`.

```
    int n; // n is use to decide the size of array 

    printf("enter the size of array:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int x[n];
    int y[n];
```

Comment: You're welcome. On SO you can say thank you by upvoting and/or accepting answers.

Comment: I cannot vote now due the stack overflow rule for 15 reputation like

Comment: @AyushTalesara See this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers